# Google Analytics - suburb location

Tags: php, google-analytics

Hi I have implemented google analytics on to my website. However it only shows the location of visitors on the country, state and city level. How do I get it to show the visitors location drilling down to suburb level?

Is it a special code I need on my website or some settings I need to do on my account or something I have to pay for ?

Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics' accuracy will very often be the best you can get.

There is [HTML5 Geolocation](http://html5demos.com/geo) (more detailed introduction [here](http://diveintohtml5.info/geolocation.html)) which can be more accurate, down to several feet if the user's machine has a GPS device. However, this kind of geolocation requires the user's explicit permission.